# Python interpreter invocation with "-c" and indentation issues

Tags: python, cmd, syntax-error, interpreter

I'm trying to invoke Python using the "-c" argument to allow me to run some arbitrary python code easily, like this:
`python.exe -c "for idx in range(10): print idx"`
Now this code works fine, from within my batch file, however, I'm running into problems when I want to do anything more than this.

Consider the following Python code:

```
foo = 'bar'
for idx in range(10):
    print idx
```

this would then give you 0-9 on the stdout. However, if I collapse this into a single line, using semicolons as delimiters, to get the following:

```
foo = 'bar';for idx in range(10):    print idx
```

and try to run it using `python.exe -c` it get a SyntaxError raised:

```
C:\Python>python.exe -c "foo = 'bar';for idx in range(10):    print idx"
  File "<string>", line 1
    foo = 'bar';for idx in range(10):    print idx
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone know how I can actually use this without switching to a separate .py file?

I'm running this from within a .cmd batch file, via the call method like so:

```
call python.exe -c "blah blah"
```

with the same error being generated.

Comment: have you try using \n as line separator ?

Comment: I just edited my post to clarify my use case. Despite the example I gave, my intent is not to run this via the command line, but instead from within a batch file. I was seeing the same SyntaxError in both the batch file and on the command line and so naively thought the solution would be the same :/

Comment: Anyway, you will incurr into quote escaping issues - Maybe it is just better to have a separate Python script and use Python to run that instead?

Comment: Yea, forcing myself into this single batch file is making things more rather than less complicated. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You need to enter the command string as a multi-line argument. With linux, this is as easy as using the enter key, e.g. (note that bash adds the `>` characters, I didn't have to type them):

```
$ python -c "foo = 'bar'
> for idx in range(10):
>     print idx"
```

On Windows though, you need to type the `^` key before hitting enter and leaving a blank line to get a newline character, e.g. (`More?` added by `cmd`)

```
C:\> python.exe -c "foo = 'bar'^
More? 
More? for idx in range(10):^
More? 
More?     print idx"
```

Comment: Ah, apologies, I didn't specify the full context of my usecase. What you've written works, and I never knew the use of caret on Windows(!) but I'm trying to invoke this from within a .cmd file via 

    `call python.exe -c "blah blah"`

Comment: @alexander Try write the program script normally, but then use `\n` where you would use a real newline.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. The \n wouldn't be parsed validly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a newline to separate the statements.  This is how I entered it into the shell:

```
$ python -c "foo = 'bar'
for idx in range(10): print idx"
```

What you wrote doesn't work because the semicolon binds tighter than the colon, so it gets confused.  By contrast, this works, for example:

```
$ python -c "foo = 'bar'; print foo"
```